# Find top-k mode from numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given a MxN Numpy matrix, I want to find top-`k` mode for each row.

I found about `scipy.stats.mode` but it only able to return top-1 mode for each row.

The returned matrix mode should be sorted by the frequency, if there are 2 element with same number of frequency, then return the most left element in original array.

Example

Input :

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2,3]
              [4,5,5,5,5,6],
              [3,3,2,2,1,1]])
```

Output(k=2) :

```
[[1,2], # 1 appears 3 times. 2 appears 2 times
 [5,4], # 5 appears 4 times. 4 and 6 appears once, choose 4
 [3,2]] # 1,2, and 3 all appears 2 times, then return 3 and 2
```

Comment: You need to write your own function to do that since `scipy.stats.mode` always returns a single value for mode if there is only one mode, else it will return the smallest value if two or more elements have the same count, so the behavior you are expecting is not directly possible.

Comment: why choose 4 in the second row? what rule are you using? and why use 3 and 2 in the third?

Comment: @yannziselman i have stated the rule. "if there are 2 element with same number of frequency, then return the most left element in original array". I choose 4 for second row because it appears first before the number 6 eventough they have same frequency

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. You should note though that if a few of the values have the same counts my code will probably return the largest values, but that will depend on how you sorted them in the first sort operation.
If there are less unique values than the number of requested modes, the respective row in the 'mode' array will be padded with 'np.nan'. The modes in the 'modes' array appear in the reverse order according to the number of their counts.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,1,1,2,2,3],
              [4,5,5,5,5,6],
              [3,3,2,2,1,1]])

modes_num = 2

# find unique values and the number of their accurances
xs = np.sort(x, axis=1)
xsd = np.concatenate([(np.diff(xs)!=0).astype(int).T, np.ones((1, x.shape[0]))]).T
idx = np.arange(xsd.shape[1])[None, :].repeat(xsd.shape[0], 0)+1
idxs = np.sort(idx*xsd, 1)
counts = np.concatenate([np.zeros((1, x.shape[0])), np.diff(idxs, 1).T]).T
unique = np.sort(xs*xsd).astype(float)
unique[counts == 0] = np.nan
# get the values with the highest numbers of counts.
countsas = np.argsort(counts)
idx0 = np.arange(x.shape[0]).repeat(modes_num)
idx1 = countsas[:, -modes_num:].flatten()
modes = unique[idx0, idx1].reshape(-1, modes_num)
```

Output:

```
array([[2., 1.],
       [6., 5.],
       [2., 3.]])
```